# Android - List activities that can handle ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT intent

Tags: android, android-intent, package-managers, action-process-text

I'm trying to list activities in Android system, that would handle ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT. In my emulator (running Android 9), I have at least two such apps, that add actions to the "overflow" menu on the toolbar shown when some text is selected (one is my own app, the action works fine, the other is Google Translate that adds "Translate" item to that menu). I'm trying to use the obvious code within an activity class:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT);
   //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT_READONLY, true);
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT, "Test");
   PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
   List<ResolveInfo> infos = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL);
```

Yet, no matter what I do, the infos list comes out empty. Am I doing something wrong, or is there any better way to list such activities in the system?

Comment: You need to set the MIME type on the `Intent`, too; e.g., `intent.setType("text/plain");`. You can get rid of the `putExtra()` call.

Comment: Great, it works, thank you very much! If you care about reputation points, or even to make this question answer easier to find by others, please post this as an answer, and I'll approve it. Thank you again!!!